Need to delay between electronic dice rolls for Catan
How would I put a delay in the reading of DIC? DIC is a photocell to ground whose light is blocked to stop dice roll. I want to put a delay so someone will not trigger another roll out of turn. The 100 delay is while the dice are rolling, changing that just changes that speed. I want to put a delay between throws of the dice. Duel dice is 2 displays on the TM1637, 2 dice displays so viewers can read from both sides.

//nano with solar cell on d8 and ground


#include <TM1637.h>

//declare pins
//int CLK = D2;
//int DIO = D3;
//int DIC = D8;
#define CLK 2
#define DIO 3
#define DIC 8
TM1637 tm(CLK, DIO);

void setup() {
  //define input output pins
  pinMode(DIC, INPUT_PULLUP);

  //initializes the pseudo-random number generator
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));

  //initialize TM1637 seven segment display
  tm.init();

  //set brightness; 0-7
  tm.set(2);
  tm.init();
}

void loop()

 {
 while (!  digitalRead(DIC)); // stop here until input is HIGH, also display holds, insert"!" before digitalRead to continuous display till button pressed
  
  tm.display(0, random(1, 7));
  tm.display(3, random(1, 7));
  delay(100);  // stop to prevent very quick change to next numbers. we can use here same Func as above, inverted of course
 //while (  digitalRead(DIC)); // stop here until input is LOW


}




It is unclear, what exactly you are trying to achieve. Please go into more details. I know nothing about what a dual dice roll is and we cannot see, what your project has to do with it. Please edit your question to make it clearer

insert a layer of separation between the reading of DIC and the resulting die roll ... replace the while statement  with if ... if DIC has been pressed,  then set a flag variable and optionally start a timer ... don't  do anything else in the if block ... next, check the state of the flag variable, and optionally the timer, then start die roll if flag is set and the timer has expired ... the flag variable can be modified by code other than the DIC reading

Thanks for yalls help! Got it going.

Your current algorithm is:
repeat:
    wait until the DIC input goes HIGH
    roll the dice

This means that, whenever the input is HIGH, your program will
continuously roll the dice. This is not what you want. Instead, you want
to roll the dice only once when that input goes HIGH. There is a
difference between being HIGH and going HIGH. What you need to add
to your program is called edge detection: you know the input pin just
went HIGH if you read it HIGH right now, whereas on the previous reading
it was LOW.
The simplest way to implement edge detection is probably to first wait
until the input is LOW, then wait again until it is HIGH:
void loop() {
    // Wait until the DIC input goes LOW.
    while (digitalRead(DIC) == HIGH) { /* wait */ }

    // Wait until the DIC input goes HIGH.
    while (digitalRead(DIC) == LOW) { /* wait */ }

    // Roll the dice.
    tm.display(0, random(1, 7));
    tm.display(3, random(1, 7));
}

This should work fine (with one caveat), if your program does not have
anything else to do. If it does have to perform other tasks, then the
blocking wait loops will be a problem. In this case, you want to detect
the edge in a non-blocking fashion, by remembering the previous state
and comparing with the one you are reading:
uint8_t previous_dic_pin_state;

void loop() {
    // Read the DIC input pin.
    uint8_t dic_pin_state = digitalRead(DIC);

    // Did the input just go HIGH?
    if (previous_dic_pin_state == LOW && dic_pin_state == HIGH) {
        // Time to roll the dice.
        tm.display(0, random(1, 7));
        tm.display(3, random(1, 7));
    }

    previous_dic_pin_state = dic_pin_state;  // save for next loop
}

The caveat is that, depending on the sensor, you may have bounces (quick
back-and-forth transitions) every time you have a legit transition. If
this is the case, then the logic gets more complicated because you also
have to wait for some time to make sure the signal is stable. The
simplest solution for such a case is to use a button debouncing library
such as Bounce2.

Thank you very much for your time.

You are almost there!!
I infer that you like the cycling through numbers as a way of simulating the dice roll, before settling on the result.
In my code, I wait for the user to wave their hand in front of the sensor, triggering the dice roll. I spin through the numbers for a second or two and then display the final result. I hold it there on the final result for a set time (in this case 30s).
The code would look something like this:

#include <TM1637.h>

//declare pins
//int CLK = D2;
//int DIO = D3;
//int DIC = D8;
#define CLK 2
#define DIO 3
#define DIC 8
TM1637 tm(CLK, DIO);


void setup() {
    //define input output pins
    pinMode(DIC, INPUT_PULLUP);

    //initializes the pseudo-random number generator
    randomSeed(analogRead(0));

    //initialize TM1637 seven segment display
    tm.init();

    //set brightness; 0-7
    tm.set(2);
    tm.init();
}


void loop()
 {
    // Wait for trigger
    while (digitalRead(DIC)); 

    // Simulate rolling the dice by cycling through the numbers 
    for (int i=0: i>20: i++)
    {
        // Display two random numbers on the 7-segment display
        tm.display(0, random(1, 7));
        tm.display(3, random(1, 7));
        
        // pause on each number for at least 0.1 second
        delay(100);
    }

    // Display the final result for at least 30 seconds
    delay(30000);
}


Thanks for your time sa, more what I am looking for.
